# How to have Nav Bar with On Click function in NextJS 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My Navbar component is located in layout.js, and contains a button with an onclick function of setting state to dark mode. However, state is managed in page.js. How do I make my navbar button in layout.js be able to change state of dark mode in page.js?

I wanted to pass my setState function as a prop to the Nav component, but realised that Nav component cannot be accessed in page.jsx.

Any help on this is appreciated!

layout.html

```js
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Nav from './Nav'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Nav></Nav>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

page.jsx

```js
"use client"

import Image from 'next/image'
import {AiFillTwitterCircle, AiFillLinkedin, AiFillYoutube} from 'react-icons/ai'
import profile from '../public/profile.JPG'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Nav from './Nav'
export default function Home() {

  [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

//trying to pass setDarkMode function as a prop to Nav component but Nav is not accessible in page.jsx


  const handleMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(currentMode=>{
      return !currentMode
    })
  } 

  

  return (
    <>
      <div className={darkMode ? "dark": ""}>
        <main className='bg-white px-10 md:px-20 mx-auto lg:max-w-[70%]'>
    
          <section className='min-h-screen py-10'>
    
            <div className='text-center p-10'>
    
              <h2 className='text-5xl py-7 text-teal-500 font-medium md:text-6xl'>Name</h2>
              <h3 className='py-5 text-xl md:text-2xl'>Aspiring Developer</h3>
              <p className='text-md py-5 text-gray-800 leading-8 md:text-xl md:leading-8'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.  Eveniet similique porro tenetur reiciendis corrupti repellat architecto perferendis quisquam quam ab officia aperiam
              </p>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div className='text-5xl flex justify-center gap-16 align-middle text-gray-600'>
              <AiFillTwitterCircle/>
              <AiFillLinkedin/>
              <AiFillYoutube/>
            </div>
    
            <div className="relative mx-auto w-80 h-80 py-16">
              <Image className="block absolute top-8 rounded-full w-80 h-80 object-cover object-right" src={profile} alt='Profile Picture'/>
            </div>
    
          </section>
    
          <section className='min-h-screen py-10'>
            <div>
              <h3 className='text-3xl md:text-4xl font-light'>My background</h3>
              <p className='text-md py-5 text-gray-800 leading-8 md:text-xl md:leading-8'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet similique porro tenetur reiciendis corrupti repellat architecto perferendis quisquam quam ab officia aperiam eaque dolorum, in laudantium temporibus ipsam assumenda natus molestiae placeat, eius aut minima! Esse similique voluptas officia tempora, nulla magni rerum ut ipsam, maxime dolorem dignissimos quia! Cumque!</p>
            </div>
    
            <div>
            </div>
    
          </section>
        </main>
      </div>
    
    </>
  )
}
```

Nav.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import {BsFillMoonStarsFill} from 'react-icons/bs'

export default function Nav({onClick}) {
  return (
    <nav className='flex justify-between mb-12 p-5  text-black gap-2'>
      <h1 className='text-xl font-burtons bold-text cursor-pointer'>DYLANWAN</h1>
      <ul className='flex items-center'>
        <li>
          <BsFillMoonStarsFill onClick={onClick} className='cursor-pointer text-2xl'/>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" className='bg-cyan-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg ml-8'>Resume</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: can you post code of your pages to your question?

Comment: Hello @nuser137, I have added the code and more explanations. What I'm trying to achieve is to pass my setDarkMode (state) function as a prop to the Nav component. The problem is that I cannot pass any props to Nav as it is not in the page.jsx file.

Comment: Hi @Dylariant, I posted my answer as I tried to solve your issue, you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I tried to do like this:

You can try to set the `setDarkMode` function in your page.jsx. I have used normal styling css in `index.css` to better understand the work of `darkMode`.

- page.jsx:

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import Nav from "./Nav";

    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState();

    const handleDarkMode = (e) => {
       setDarkMode(e.target.value ? "light" : "dark");
    };
 
    return (
          //..
          <div className={darkMode ? "dark" : "light"}>
            <Nav onChange={handleDarkMode} />
          </div>
         //...
    )
```

Here, in the above snippets you need to pass `<Nav />` component to your page.jsx and pass `onChange` as a prop.

- Nav.jsx

```
    export default function Nav({ onChange }) {
        <BsFillMoonStarsFill
         onClick={onChange}
         //...
        />
    }
```

In Nav, pass that `onChange` prop to `onClick` attr of `<BsFillMoonStarsFill />`.

- index.css (used normal styling instead of tailwind CSS)

```
   /*.....*/

   .dark {
     background: #222;
     color: #fff;
   }

  .light {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
   }

   /*....*/
```

Feel free to mess around in this [live demo code-sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-paper-m7jtff?file=/src/Nav.js).

I hope this will help you.